# Changing Partition scheme

Tags: windows, partitioning, gpt

I want to change my partition scheme from MBR to GUID. Is there a way to do this without any data loss. I have Windows 8 installed. Will my OS boot after changing the partition scheme??
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change from the [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) to the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitioning scheme without losing data *within* your partitions. My own [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `sgdisk`, and `cgdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) utility can do this, and I believe some commercial Windows tools can, too. (The standard Windows tools can only do a destructive conversion, in which you'll lose your original partitions.) There are some caveats:

- Depending on your partition layout, you may need to shrink the last partition by a few sectors. Theoretically, you might need to do the same for the first partition, too, but this is extremely rare.
- Some partition meta-data (type codes, etc.) will be lost or changed. This isn't normally a problem.
- Your disk will no longer be bootable. Restoring bootability *may* be possible, depending on your OS and firmware -- see below. In many cases you'll need to create at least one new partition to make the system bootable again.
- Any change to partition tables is potentially risky. The MBR-to-GPT change actually involves fewer and less-complex changes than, say, resizing a partition; but an error can be equally disastrous. Back up first.

The issue of bootability is complex. Windows ties its partition table type to its firmware, at least for bootable disks. Windows boots from MBR disks *only* on BIOS firmware or on EFIs with BIOS/CSM/legacy support enabled; and from GPT disks *only* on EFI firmware. Thus, if you're booting Windows from this disk, you'll have to convert it from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting. This is not possible on older computers (most machines from before mid-2011), which have true BIOS firmware. If your computer is newer than mid-2011, it may well have an EFI, in which case you can install the Windows EFI boot loader and be up and running. I've done this conversion once, but the page that described the procedure has been removed. I found [this other one,](https://sysadminblogger.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/converting-a-windows-8-1-bios-installation-to-uefi/) (scroll down to "Conversion to UEFI"), but I've not tried its procedure, so I can't promise it will work.

If the disk you want to convert is a data (non-boot) disk, you can convert it without boot worries; Windows (Vista SP1 and later) can use a GPT data disk even when booted in BIOS mode from an MBR disk. In some cases, adding a second disk, transferring Windows to it, and using the original disk as a GPT data disk will work fine, too.

All this said, the real question is: ***why?*** There are valid reasons to do an MBR-to-GPT conversion, but the effort and risks involved are such that you should really be doing this only if you've got a compelling reason. The usual "compelling reason" is that your disk is actually a RAID array and you're adding enough storage to it that it's passing the 2TiB limit, which is where MBR maxes out (assuming a 512-byte sector size). If you're just curious about GPT, then it's better to try it out on a test disk or in a virtual machine than to risk your main computer.